# Not able to read/access data from JSON.?

Tags: jquery, json

Trying to access/read data from `JSON`, which is giving me undefined value.

Have a string, using `JSON`.parse converting it to object

```
str = '{"content":[{"newstitle":"a","newsdesc":"a","newsimage":"a"}],"leftnav":[{"navtitle":"b","navdesc":"b","navimage":"b"}]}'

var finalobj = JSON.parse(str);
alert(finalobj.leftnav.navtitle);
```

So the alert output should be value "b" but it is returning "undefined".

Thanks in advance

Comment: use `console.log(finalobj)` and inspect the result using firebug (firefox extension), will help you a lot to view the javascript objects

Comment: Yes, using console.log helped for debugging... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `[]` since leftnav is in array( array of objects)..and `[0]` because `navtitle` is in 0 index of array

try this

```
alert(finalobj.leftnav[0].navtitle);
```

Comment: Thanks bipen... it worked...my bad... was considering leftnav as object itself...

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
alert(finalobj.leftnav[0].navtitle);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alert(finalobj.leftnav[0].navtitle);
```